# Proof that $ax \equiv 1 \mod{n}$ has no solutions when $a$ and $n$ aren't co-prime?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

Does this proof work? Is there a simpler one (precluding citing other theorems)?

Suppose $ax \equiv 1 \bmod{n}$. Then $ax = kn + 1$. We have some $d = \gcd(a, n)$ such that $a = da'$, $n = dn'$, and $d > 1$. So $da'x = kdn' + 1 \implies d(a'x - n'k) = 1 \implies a'x - n'k = 1 \mathbin/ d$. The LHS is an interger, but for $d > 1$, the RHS isn't. So the equality cannot hold.

Comment: That's fine. You can just conclude $d\mid 1$ rather than writing $\frac{1}{d}$, which requires the addition of the rational numbers to your proof.

Comment: Your solution is correct. You can also try proving the converse. That is, if $\gcd(a,n)=1$, then $ax\equiv 1\pmod{n}$ has a solution.

Comment: @caffeinemachine Would such a proof basically boil down to proving the correctness of the ~~Euclidean~~ extended Euclidean algorithm? Or is there a simpler (non-constructive?) proof?

Comment: You can 'write' in a neat way without getting into Euclidean Algorithm. Define $d=\min\{ax+by>0:x,y\in\mathbf Z\}$. Show using that division algorithm that $d|a$ and $d|b$.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider this one:
Let $ax \equiv 1$ mod $n$ 
Suppose $(a,n) = d$ 
So if $ ax \equiv 1$ mod $n$ $\rightarrow ax = kn + 1, k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Now we only want to consider: 
$ax + (-n)k = 1$ and this is a diofantine linear equation, so this equation has a solution if and only if $(a,-n) \lvert 1$, now it's clear that $(a,-n) = (a,n) = d $. Therefore $ d \lvert 1$ so $ (a,n) = d = 1$.